# Running a Python function for a specific duration

Tags: python

Total sleep time should be 60 secs and each check should be in 5 secs interval.
How should I use count variable to trace the count of the total execution

```
def test(a):
    count=0
    while True:
        if a < 10:
            print("ok")
            return True
        count = count+1
        time.sleep(5)

        if(count == 12):
            return False

print(test(a=40))
```

the while loop should stop executing after 60 secs and return false, the each check interval is 5 secs. I am confused that where should I increment the count, before time.sleep(5) or after time.sleep(5). what will be the solution to see that the time.sleep is been executed for 12 times and it has been 60 secs of waiting and return false

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
def test(a):
    count=0
    while True:
        if a < 10:
            print("ok")
            return True
        count = count+1
        time.sleep(5)

        if(count == 12):
            return False

print ("Start : %s" % time.ctime())
print(test(a=40))
print ("End : %s" % time.ctime())[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.time()`

```
import time
max_time = 60

start_time = time.time()  # remember when we started


    def test(a):
    count=0
    while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time:
        if a < 10:
            print("ok")


print(test(a=40))
```